# Overloading operator() and using within class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have successfully overloaded the () operator.

```
inline real& Array::operator ()(int j,int i)
{                   
    //TODO checks                          
   return array_[i + j*xSize_];            
}
```

It also works just fine. However i didn't figured out, how to access it within the class itself. For example the following function, which prints all the elements:

```
for(int y = ySize_ -1; y >= 0; --y)
{
    for( int x = 0; x < xSize_; ++x)
    {
        std::cout << this(x,y);
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

How do i access it then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following syntax:

```
(*this)(x, y);
```

or the longer form:

```
this->operator()(x, y);
```

or

```
operator()(x,y);
```